# R: how to use a variable in a loop? A1, A2, A3

Tags: r

A small example. I created 'A1', 'A2', ..., 'A10', in the first loop. I want to get the mean of them in another loop? how should I do that?

```
d= 5
for(i in 1:10) 
{ 
  nam <- paste("A", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, rnorm(3)+d)
}

for(i in 1:10)
{
  nam <- paste("A", i, sep = "")
  mean(nam)
}
```

the above doesn't work because nam is a string.

Thanks,
PS

Comment: I think you should look up how to use vectors/lists, instead of creating many variables. Case in point, your loops should be written as `a = replicate(10, rnorm(3) + d)` and `sapply(a, mean)`.

Comment: If for some reason you actually _need_ to do something like in your example, you'd want to use [`get`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html), i.e. `get(nam)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not how we do things in R. Try this:

```
vals <- replicate(10,{rnorm(3) + 5},simplify = FALSE)
vals <- setNames(vals,paste0("A",1:10))

lapply(vals,mean)
```

and try to forget you ever heard about the function `assign`, at least for the time being.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote for the `assign` comment. I don't know where this comes from but I keep seeing this almost every day. Maybe some weird online courses.

Comment: I always assumed that kind of approach to this problem stems from SAS. It's a natural way to approach the problem for a SAS user.  So just like almost all of the problems in my life I'll blame this one on SAS.

Comment: @RHertel I have recently commented, rhetorically, that the more I see these kinds of mistakes, the harder it is for me to, ahem, _assign_ blame to the user, as opposed to R making it difficult to intuit the "right" way to do things.

Comment: @joran - I'm not willing to *assign* blame to R solely.  If you aren't being taught how to approach this kind of problem it's certainly understandable how one could take this kind of approach to solve the problem. I remember when I first learned Java (my first language) I once solved a simulation problem by creating something like 32 variables by hand to represent each of the 32 possible outcomes instead of using an array because I hadn't learned about them yet. Not my proudest moment after learning about arrays but people approach problems with what they know right?

Comment: @Dason Yeah, me neither. It's more a shift in percentages.

Comment: @joran Then I can only hope that the shift indicates people running from SAS and moving to R!